# ImportError: No module named appName.settings django 1.8 + Apache + mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache

I know several similar questions have been posted, but none of their solution works for me. 
Could you help figure out how to resolve this issue?
Any help is appreciated.

version info:

```
apache2 2.4.7
os Ubuntu 14.04
django 1.8
```

Error message

```
MOD_PYTHON ERROR

ProcessId:      15796
Interpreter:    '127.0.1.1'

ServerName:     '127.0.1.1'
DocumentRoot:   '/var/www/html'

URI:            '/'
Location:       None
Directory:      None
Filename:       '/home/stevenhe/mywork/src/listbaby/listbaby/wsgi.py'
PathInfo:       '/'

Phase:          'PythonHandler'
Handler:        'mod_python.publisher'

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1537, in HandlerDispatch
    default=default_handler, arg=req, silent=hlist.silent)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1229, in _process_target
    result = _execute_target(config, req, object, arg)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1128, in _execute_target
    result = object(arg)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/publisher.py", line 204, in handler
    module = page_cache[req]

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1059, in __getitem__
    return import_module(req.filename)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 296, in import_module
    log, import_path)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 680, in import_module
    execfile(file, module.__dict__)

  File "/home/stevenhe/mywork/src/listbaby/listbaby/wsgi.py", line 18, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)

ImportError: No module named listbaby.settings
```

**My Project structure**:

- project path: `/home/stevenhe/mywork/src/listbaby`
- app name: `listbaby`
- abs path to wsgi.py = `/home/stevenhe/mywork/src/listbaby/lisbaby/wsgi.py`
- abs path to settings.py = `/home/stevenhe/mywork/src/listbaby/lisbaby/settings.py`

content of wsgi.py

```
import os, sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
#sys.path.append('/home/stevenhe/mywork/src/listbaby') if I add this line, http simply returns 404 error
sys.path.append('/home/stevenhe/mywork/src/listbaby/listbaby')

os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"]="listbaby.settings"

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

content of apache2.conf

```
   WSGIScriptAlias / /home/stevenhe/mywork/src/listbaby/listbaby/wsgi.py
   WSGIPythonPath /home/stevenhe/mywork/src/listbaby

<Directory /home/stevenhe/mywork/src/listbaby/listbaby>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a package to install that is listed in INSTALLED_APPS. This was a regression - if you upgrade to the latest Django 1.8.x, it will tell you the missing app. Install it via pip and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I upgraded django to 1.8.8, and service apache2 start, but got the same error. Again, it tells me it can not find ImportError: No module named listbaby.settings.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure manage.py file inside your project has os.environ set to  listbaby.settings.

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "listbaby.settings")
```